# File preview not available on loading the images from server in file pond

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, filepond

[checkout the code snippet, i have tried

```js
Please checkout the code i tried to fetch the images from the s3 bucket. Fetching is accomplished but unable to preview the fetched image. 

<FilePond
style = {{marginTop:'10px'}}
files={files}
allowMultiple={true}
allowReorder={true}
onupdatefiles={setFiles}
imagePreviewHeight = "125px"
server={{
           load: (source, load, error, progress, abort, headers) => {
           var myRequest = new Request(source);
           fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
           response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
           load(myBlob);
           });
         });
        },
     process: null
  }}
labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
/>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyZJa.png)

Comment: You probably have a CORS error in your developer console, make sure you've configured CORS correctly. More here: https://pqina.nl/pintura/docs/v8/faq/resolve-cors-errors/

Comment: `imagePreviewHeight = "125px"` that shouldn't be in pixels but a number, so `imagePreviewHeight={125}` additionally make sure you've loaded the image preview styles and registered the image preview plugin with FilePond