# CORS issue while previewing images using filepond and s3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, amazon-s3, filepond

S3 bucket is configured but i am still getting the CORS error while previewing the images.

Preparing the files payload

```
function readyPayload(){
        setFiles([])
        imgs && imgs.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.orderId) > parseInt(b.orderId) ? 1 : -1)
        .map((item, idx) => {
            setFiles(
                prevState => [
                    ...prevState,
                    {
                        source: item.imageUrl,
                        // options: {
                        //     type:"local"
                        // }
                    }
                ]
            )
        })
    }
```

The Filepond component

```
<FilePond
      files={files}
      allowMultiple={true}
      allowReorder={true}
      onupdatefiles={setFiles}
      onreorderfiles = {setFiles}
      onremovefile = {(error, file) => deleteImgs(file.filename)}
      imagePreviewHeight = "125px"
  />
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341941/file-preview-not-available-on-loading-the-images-from-server-in-file-pond

Comment: Nope, its working fine in mozilla but not in chrome. Also, won't there be performances issue if we'll make no cache into s3 ? Is there any fix for it in the plugin itself. Like the way  we can define the file state and the filepond component ?